# How to plot box plots for all keys in a dict, instead of clubbing all of them into one

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
d1={'M0':870.24,'M1':50.2,'M2':30,'M3':22.06,...}
```

trying to do boxplot for all keys, with corresponding values, below code is clubbing all of them

```
 labels,data=d1.keys(),d1.values()
    print(labels)
    print(data)
    plt.boxplot(data)
    plt.xticks(range(1,len(labels)+1),labels)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
how to have independent point for all the entries?

Comment: What's your expected output? `data` is just a list of values, so `boxplot(data)` will only create one boxplot showing the distribution of `data`.

Comment: And `dict` keys are unique, so each key will only have 1 value. If your intent is to create 1 boxplot per key, that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: You really should remove `plt.xticks(range(1,len(labels)+1),labels)` because  you are plotting only one boxplot.

Answer (score -1):

this did the trick, i think the values needs to be a list.

```
def combList(*args):
    return map(list,zip(*args))

csv_data = open('./fbg3.csv','r')
data = list(csv.reader(csv_data))
print(data)
dict0 = dict(zip(data[0],combList(*data[1:])))   
dict1={key:list(map(float,value)) for key,value in dict0.items()}
print(dict1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(dict1.values())
ax.set_xticklabels(dict1.keys())
plt.show()
```